# expected primary-expression before ')' token : c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to C/C++, I've been using python, And I'm trying to get current time and partition it, But I'm having a problem acquiring the current time using `ctime`.

```
float t2lmst(){
    QString t = ctime(time_t); //line with error
    QString year =t.substr(20,4);
    QString monthn =t.substr(4,3);
    QString day =t.substr(8,2);
    QString hour =t.substr(11,2);
    QString minute =t.substr(14,2);
    QString second =t.substr(17,2);
}
```

The error is exactly:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a type to a function. You need to pass actual objects/structs. `ctime` takes a pointer to a `time_t`.

```
time_t now = time(0);
QString t = ctime(&now);
```

Also `QString` doesn't have a `substr` member function. Look at [`mid`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#mid) and related functions instead. Or use `localtime`/`gmtime`. Or better yet, use the Qt date and time objects.